# RESTful way of updating a model from different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application has a User model.

In the `home#index` view, I present a form for the current User to update their email address, using `form_for`.

Now if my application is to remain RESTful, as I understand it the Haml in `app/views/home/index.html.haml` should look something like:

```
- form_for current_user, :url =>  { :action => "update", :controller => "user" } do |f|
    = f.text_field :email
    = f.submit "Update email address"
```

My question is as follows: what is the correct way to get the User model to redirect to the `home#index` view after the update?

Comment: I would add a `?return_to=index` query string to the URL, or simply perform the update via AJAX.

Comment: Thanks. I should say I can think of a number of ways of 'solving' this problem - I'm really looking for a bit of a steer on the "Rails way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I actually reverted to using [resourceful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)... far cleaner.

Thanks for the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can give `redirect` to your `format.html` on your `controller def update`, like

```
format.html { redirect to :back }
```

this will redirect to the page that send request before.

That's the simplest way..!